# Does drupal create new file in image styles?

Tags: views, media

There are many images with 3000X2000 dimensions and I created a view of their content type. I also created a new image style, it is 90X70. This view displays the images in this size, but here is my question, which image size is loaded on the page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an image style, a folder is created in `/sites/default/files/styles/` that holds processed versions of your image.  When you select to use that style in views or anywhere else, only the processed image is loaded.  It wouldn't load the full size image if you have it set to the 90x70 style.

Answer (score 0):

use [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and simply right click on an image in your webpage and see the image URL and Dimensions with `Inspect this Element`.

People can give you an verbatim answer -- but if you find the answer yourself you'll learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own image preset or re-size the existing one by configuring the option under:

```
admin/config/media/image-styles
```

Then use this image style accordingly by selecting the required style in configuration of image field